# How can I create a MYSQL database template for others

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP hosted on github that stores some information in a database when run. The database itself is very simple (one table with three columns).

What's the best way to encode the database structure in a file for others who want to use my code?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable;` ?

Comment: I probably don't understand the question: can't you just export it into a SQL file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you just need to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName`

At that point, you can copy and paste it into a *.sql file.

Comment: Don't forget to commit the .sql file

Comment: Ok so I did that, had to put a semicolon at the end of the file.

This gives me ``CREATE TABLE `push` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `token` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;``

Answer (score 2):

You can get the exact definition of your schema using mysqldump:

```
mysqldump --no-data -u username -ppassword dbname > filename.sql
```

That will dump all the structure information, but it won't include any of your data (that is, the contents of the tables won't be included).

Comment: I think this is what I was after.

Comment: ok not quite. I think the other answer gives me something a bit simpler.

Comment: Yeah, but not as portable or convenient or easy to use. You have to type "SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename" for each table, and then cut and paste the result into your file. Mysqldump on the command line is a easy and powerful tool to get used to using.